# How to take parts of a text from a string in R?

Tags: r, regex

I'm researching how the native language can affect publication. I have downloaded the BibTeX from Web of Science and imported it in R using bibliometrix package. There's a column in this data frame indicating authors' addresses. For example:

```
[1] "SEGALLA, R (CORRESPONDING AUTHOR), INST FED EDUC CIENCIA \\& TECNOL MATO GROSSO, CAMPUS CACERES PROF OLEGARIO BALDO, BR-78201382 VILA REAL DIST IND, CACERES, BRAZIL.; SEGALLA, ROSANE, INST FED EDUC CIENCIA \\& TECNOL MATO GROSSO, CAMPUS CACERES PROF OLEGARIO BALDO, BR-78201382 VILA REAL DIST IND, CACERES, BRAZIL.; SEGALLA, ROSANE; CERDEIRA MORELLATO, LEONOR PATRICIA, UNIV ESTADUAL PAULISTA UNESP, INST BIOCIENCIAS, DEPT BIODIVERSIDADE, LAB FENOL, RIO CLARO, BRAZIL.; PINHEIRO, FABIO, UNIV ESTADUAL CAMPINAS, INST BIOL, DEPT BIOL VEGETAL, CAMPINAS, BRAZIL."
```

I have a vector containing all names of countries accepted by the united nation, something like this:

```
  [1] "Afghanistan"                      "Angola"
```

and so on...

What I need to do is to extract the name of the countries of the authors' addresses. Considering the example above, I need to obtain Brazil, Brazil, Brazil, but I don't know exactly how to do this.
I have tried to use grep and str_extract but I didn't succeed.
Also, I need to do this for every observation of my data frame, which has more than 2k observations.

Comment: Can you show us the code, you already have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Why don't you join all the countries to an alternation (`|`) in your regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
txt <- "SEGALLA, R (CORRESPONDING AUTHOR), INST FED EDUC CIENCIA \\& TECNOL MATO GROSSO, CAMPUS CACERES PROF OLEGARIO BALDO, BR-78201382 VILA REAL DIST IND, CACERES, BRAZIL.; SEGALLA, ROSANE, INST FED EDUC CIENCIA \\& TECNOL MATO GROSSO, CAMPUS CACERES PROF OLEGARIO BALDO, BR-78201382 VILA REAL DIST IND, CACERES, BRAZIL.; SEGALLA, ROSANE; CERDEIRA MORELLATO, LEONOR PATRICIA, UNIV ESTADUAL PAULISTA UNESP, INST BIOCIENCIAS, DEPT BIODIVERSIDADE, LAB FENOL, RIO CLARO, BRAZIL.; PINHEIRO, FABIO, UNIV ESTADUAL CAMPINAS, INST BIOL, DEPT BIOL VEGETAL, CAMPINAS, BRAZIL."
countries <- c("Afghanistan", "Angola", "Brazil")

ptn <- paste0("\\b(", paste(countries, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")
ptn
# [1] "\\b(Afghanistan|Angola|Brazil)\\b"

regmatches(txt, gregexpr(ptn, txt, ignore.case = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "BRAZIL" "BRAZIL" "BRAZIL" "BRAZIL"
```